# When change a MovieClip's parent, would it dispatch Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE event?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I change a `button`'s parent use `addChild` function, the  `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` was dispatched, but it is not always dispatched.
Is it a normal phenomenon？

Comment: Could you show the code that you have used to get that behavior ?

Comment: That's not expected, unless you `addChild` to a container that is *not* on the stage's display list.

Comment: Wait, I take this back. If you `addChild` to a different container it will dispatch `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`. It won't if you `addChild` to the container it was already added to.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it too, Though the new parent is in the stage's display list, the event will be dispatched too. And I think it is because when a child change his parent, it would be removed from the old parent, and then causes this. However, I think it is not excepted.